# How to get record count if count is already used in group by function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using the below query gets me some result,how to get the count of result if count is already used in a group by function and  get count of each date.

```
Select column1, column2, count(*)
from tablename
where column_date between 'date1' and 'date2'
group by column1, column2
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by date then you need to add date in your inner query's select list. You might try below query:

```
select column_date,count(*) from (
Select column_date ,column 1, column 2, count () row_count from tablename where column_date between 'date1' 
and 'date2' group by date,column 1, column 2 having count ()>1) t
group by date
```

Please let me know if you face any difficulties.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error as no column was specified for column 6 of 't' and also the date which you mentioned above is the column name which has date right ?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rowcount' also there is error showing under t. Sorry I'm new at this so forgive me for any noob mistakes.

Comment: Would you please share your actual query? So t hat, I can try to resolve syntax errors.

Comment: I have made necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count all the rows your query has returned the you can achieve through this:

```
select count(*) from (
Select column 1, column 2, count () from tablename where column date between 'date1' 
and 'date2' group by column 1, column 2 having count ()>1) t
```

Comment: Hi this worked, thank you so much for your help also is there a way to show the count date wise. For eg : if date is from 1st to 5th and the count is 100 is it possible to show count for each day eg : 1st - 25, 2nd -30,3rd -45 and so on ?